# Convert base64 encoded database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with all the data in a base64 string. What I need to do is pull every row from the database, decode it and then update it in the database.

I've written a little script but it only converts one row. How can I get it to run through all rows and convert them?

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mod_manage_testimonials") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$client_id = $row['client_id'];
$title = base64_decode($row['title']);
$content = base64_decode($row['content']);
$link = base64_decode($row['link']);

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE mod_manage_testimonials SET title='$title',content='$content',link='$link' WHERE client_id='$client_id'") 
or die(mysql_error());  

}
```

Comment: If it gives you an error, add some SQL string escaping. And why would it convert only one row if it's a while loop already? Or what did you mean by 'row'?

Comment: It was obvious really. Thank you mario for pointing it out. mysql_escape_string()

Comment: better `mysql_real_escape_string()`...

Answer (score 1):

Don't overwrite the result `$result` from the `SELECT`-query with the return value of the the `UPDATE`-query

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE mod_manage_testimonials SET title='$title',content='$content',link='$link' WHERE client_id='$client_id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

As far as I can see `$result` from the `UPDATE`-query has no deeper meaning, so you can just omit it.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE mod_manage_testimonials SET title='$title',content='$content',link='$link' WHERE client_id='$client_id'") or die(mysql_error());
```